# Are there any good open source / free metric tracking tools?

Tags: analytics, metrics

I like metrics both code related and not  I'm wondering if there are any general metric tracking tools- basically something that I can use to track anything (weight, # of bugs, gas mileage).

Bonus points for the following features:

- graphs
- an API
- open source
- other analytics capabilities
- customizable parts (more customization is better)

Comment: CouchDB + HTML5 + Some Graph API, anyone?

Comment: In terms of statistics, there's nothing more sophisticated than R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [NDepend for .NET](http://www.ndepend.com/) , [JArchitect for Java](http://www.JArchitect.com/) and [CppDepend for C++](http://www.cppdepend.com) . These tools come with [graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx) , [Code Querying and Ruling API](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) and [dozens of code metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx), they have a free trial but they are no free.

Comment: You might want to disclose that you're a dev for NDepend …

Comment: Yes I am, it is written in my Stackoverflow ID which : Patrick Smacchia - NDepend

Comment: Just updated my ID to Patrick from NDepend team

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately they're quite expensive for the smaller project I had in mind.